# Saving objects using only business keys. [Hibernate]

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I have task that I want to save some ParentObject but this ParentObject have relation to childrenObject by PK on tables. But on my logic I don't have that PK only business key(code). And there is my problem how to save parenObject with FK of this childrenObject when I have only business key(code). (business key is unique like PK in children table).

I can do it manualy by fetching childrenTable by business key then update that PK witch is related to parentObject. But I think it's stiupid and I have hope that Hibernate can do it for me.

code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_object")
public class ParenObject {
@Id
    private Integer id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "code", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "children_id")
    private ChildrenObject childrenObject;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "children_object")
public class ChildrenObject {
@Id
    private Integer id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "code", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

}
```

using CRUD repository I want just to simple save that object:

```
{ "id": null,
"code": "12345",
"name": "Parent Entity",
"childrenObject": {
 "id":null,
 "code":"09876",
 "name": "Children Entity"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately seems you have to fetch it first. As mentioned in [The best way to map a @NaturalId business key with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-naturalid-business-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/):

> Hibernate already has a well-established logic for loading and associating entities by their identifier in the Persistence Context.

and seems the same is true for storing objects and Hibernate relies heavily on the `@Id` column. Even to load an entity using its natural identifier, it first executes a query to fetch the actual `@Id` and then makes the second query to fetch the entity itself (based on an example from the same article):

```
SELECT c.id AS id1_0_
FROM ChildrenObject c
WHERE c.code = 'child-code'

SELECT c.id AS id1_0_0_,
       c.code AS code2_0_0_,
       c.name AS name3_0_0_
FROM ChildrenObject c
WHERE c.id = 1
```